# Select nodes Linq to Xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

XML file format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset>    
        <url>
            <loc>element1</loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.2</priority>
        </url>
        <url>
            <loc>element2</loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.2</priority>
        </url>
    <urlset>
```

I want to select all "loc" nodes (element1, element2), but this not work!!!

```
 foreach (XElement item in document.Elements("url").Descendants("loc")) // Change into what?
 {
      urlList.Add(item.Value);
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're going from `document.Elements("url")` instead of `document.Root.Elements("url")`... so it's looking for a *root* element of `url`, which doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
List<string> urlList = doc.Root.Elements("url")
                               .Elements("loc")
                               .Select(x => (string) x)
                               .ToList();
```

Note that I haven't used `Descendants` here, as the `loc` elements are all directly beneath `url` elements anyway.

Another alternative you could use if the *only* `loc` elements are the right ones anyway, is just:

```
List<string> urlList = doc.Descendants("loc")
                          .Select(x => (string) x)
                          .ToList();
```

(I'm assuming `urlList` was empty beforehand... for this sort of situation I like to use LINQ for the whole operation and eliminate `foreach` loops that are just adding to a collection.)

EDIT: The code works for me. Here's a short but complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
    <urlset>    
        <url>
            <loc>element1</loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.2</priority>
        </url>
        <url>
            <loc>element2</loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.2</priority>
        </url>
    </urlset>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        List<string> urlList = doc.Root
                                  .Elements("url")
                                  .Elements("loc")
                                  .Select(x => (string) x)
                                  .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(urlList.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon! I used your code but my urlList still empty! :( (i parse xml from a string).

Comment: @Chelsea_cole: Works for me - I've posted a complete program showing it working. Note that I had to fix up your original XML, from `<urlset>` at the end to `</urlset>`. Please try my code, and then see what the difference is between that and what you were trying...

Comment: Your code really work! But still not for me :( Maybe it's because my streamreader string?)

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\data.xml");
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);

Comment: It's more likely to be because your XML isn't the same as what you've posted. But it's not a great idea to parse XML like that anyway: it's assuming UTF-8, whereas `XDocument` can do the right thing for multiple encodings; you should use a `using` statement instead of closing explicitly; to read the whole of a file you can use `File.ReadAllText`; you can do all of this in one call anyway with `XDocument.Load(string)`.

Comment: @CJohnson: I suggest you ask a new question with a short but complete example of what you're trying to do then. It's impossible to tell what's wrong just from your comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<urlset>    
        <url>
            <loc>element1</loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.2</priority>
        </url>
        <url>
            <loc>element2</loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.2</priority>
        </url>
    </urlset>");
var locElements = xDoc.Descendants("url").SelectMany(el => el.Descendants("loc"));
```

Comment: That will return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>` which I don't think is what was wanted...

Comment: The way that `Descendants()` works, there's no need to use `SelectMany` - there's an overload which *starts* with an `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = for x in xDoc.Descendants("url")
            select (string)x.Element("loc");

foreach (string loc in query)
{
    urlList.Add(loc);
}
```